# Merging polygons based on five first digits in id using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, merge, dissolve, polygon-creation

I have a shapefile with 1364 polygons in the Stockholm area:

[image: attribute table of shapefile]

But the "areas" are too detailed - I want to make fewer and bigger polygons. I would like to merge/dissolve all 'BASKOD2010' id's based on the five first digits. As an example from my table above, I want to merge **35102**80, **35102**70 and **35102**60 into one polygon.

Can anyone explain how I do this in QGIS?

Comment: You could create a new field, then use field calculator to populate it with the first 5 digits of your other field (in Python: BASKOD2010[0:5], then dissolve on the new field.

Answer (score 7):

If the field type is not string, then the simplest way is to create a new field with `Text` type of 5 characters length. Then in the field calculator go to `Update existing field` and select the newly created field. Then use the following expression:

```
to_string("NewField")
```

The numbers will be truncated to the first 5 digits.

However, if the existing field is already of `Text` type, then create a new field as above and use the following expression, and it will do the job:

```
left("NewField" ,5)
```

[image]

The column in red color is the original column, and the column in green color is the selected first 5 digits.

Then use dissolve tool from `Vector -> Geoprocessing tools -> Dissolve`, if you are using QGIS 2.14.7, and select the `NewField` as a base to dissolve your polygons. If you are using QGIS 2.16.3, then go to `Processing toolbox -> QGIS geoalgorithms -> Vector geometry tools -> Dissolve`

The output of dissolve tool using the `NewField` column (in this example the column name is `EndDateSub`) is as follows:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't quite answer the question.  You've shown how to create a field of the first 5 characters.  Not how to merge the polygons.

Comment: @Fezter thanks for your comment, I will update my answer to use dissolve tool based on the new field.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Menu Processing > Toolbox > Aggregate` and aggregate based on the field `BASKOD2000`, grouping together those values that share the five first digits with this expression for `Group by expression`:

```
left("BASKOD2000", 5)
```